# How to enforce stand alone mode after returning from opened webpage from within the standalone mode?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have this issue when I connect my app to stripe customer portal that portal opens In some sort of external browser , once I am done and want to return back to my app , the Stan deal one mode is broken, and the page is reduced in size.

Portal lower part
[image]

Back in my app
[[image]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kzX8.jpg)

As you can se I get this gray box as it repeats the browser box, how to solve this.